# Imitation of OpenTopoMap with DEM-data

Tags: dem, opentopomap

I'm trying to imitate the OpenTopoMap with freely available DEM-Data. Which parameters do I have to change in my hillshaded DEM to get a similar look?

[image: Is] [image: Want]

Comment: It looks like the top hillshade is using the default altitude and azimuth of any hillshade algorithm.  The lower hillshade looks like a multi-directional hillshade.  These would also be available in ArcGIS, ArcPro, and QGIS.   See this link: https://opengislab.com/blog/tag/Multidirectional+hillshade+QGIS

Comment: Thanks a lot, that already gave some improvements. But still it seems that in the OpenTopoMap the low-elevation pixel are more smooth and rather white, which gives a more soft look and emphasizes the mountain ranges. Any idea how to adapt to that?